# How to define next line in a list for label

Tags: r

I've been put in charge of automating the graph production at work and need a specific way of displaying the scale on our bar plots. currently what we have is i.imgur.com/bWjk9.png

and they would like the value of each of the scales listed below. When i change the scale it comes out like this.

i.imgur.com/1D9up.png

And the way they want it is like the way don't know (9) is displayed

Here's my code for the graph which looks up the scale elsewhere using barplot2

```
plot.graph <- function(data, px, py, scale_lab){
  par(mar=c(5.1, 4, 1, 2))
  #Plotting the Barplot
 barplot2(summary(data),
  #main = strwrap(heading, width = 50),
  xlab = "Response",
  ylab = "Number of Responses",
  prcol = "#FAF4E6",
  col = "#800000",
  space = 1.5,
  ylim = c(0, max(summary(data))+2),
  names.arg = sapply(scale_lab,wordwrap,USE.NAMES=TRUE),

  plot.grid = TRUE)
 points(px, py, pch=21, cex=4, col="black", bg="yellow", lwd=1)
 par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cameron.

Comment: What is `wordwrap` function? It seems responsible for labels.

Comment: basically it was so that the labels didn't run into one another. wordwrap <- function(string,charwidth=14){
  paste(strwrap(string,width=charwidth),collapse="\n")
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself,

for those who are interested all that was needed was

```
mtext(text= c("(1)", "(2)", "(3)", "(4)", "(5)", "(9)"),side = 1, line = 2, outer = FALSE, at = c(2, 4.5, 7, 9.5, 12, 14.5))
```